# Rails - incorrect google static map - lat long correct for given address -Active Admin - image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, activeadmin, google-maps-static-api

ActiveAdmin Rails 4 Google Static map issue
The code below shows the correct lat and long for the give addresses but when used in googlemap static map it show the completely incorrect map. Any reason you can think of? If I manually place the lat and long into the http: map string the correct map appears.

```html
ActiveAdmin.register Address do

  permit_params :address, :longitude, :latitude
  # See permitted parameters documentation:
  # https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
  #
  #
  # or
  #
  # permit_params do
  #   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
  #   permitted << :other if resource.something?
  #   permitted
  # end


  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :address
    actions
  end

  filter :address

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Address Details" do
      f.inputs :address
    end
    f.actions
    end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      # other rows
      row :address
      row :latitude
      row :longitude
      content do
      render 'googlemap'
      end
      row :addressMap do
    image_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{:latitude},#{:longitude}&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

end up addin it as a partial

changed activeadmin address form /app/admin/address.rb

```html
  show do

    attributes_table do
      # other rows
      row :address
      row :latitude
      row :longitude
     end

# renders app/views/admin/addresses/_googlemap.html.erb
    render partial: 'googlemap'
    active_admin_comments
  end
```

and the partial to /app/views/admin/adresses/_google.html.erb

```html
<%= image_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{@address.latitude},#{@address.longitude}&zoom=18&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:1%7C#{@address.latitude},#{@address.longitude}"
%>
```